# Get и Post запросы.

Tags: php

Так вот, есть сайт ["Почты России"](http://russianpost.ru/rp/servise/ru/home/postuslug/trackingpo) - на нём есть сервис, где можно посмотреть статус Ваших посылок. Введя идентификатор, мы передаем скрипту его методом POST. Но, естественно, после закрытия страницы, нам снова придется вводить идентификатор. Недавно мне понадобилось иметь прямую ссылку на этот сервис, с моим идентификатором (чтоб каждый раз его не вводить). И мне кроме как GET в голову нечего не пришло. После нескольких часов безрезультатной битвой с адресной строкой и исходным кодом. У меня нечего не вышло. Может кто сможет помочь? Или я вообще зря стараюсь и отправить данные, которые по задумке были для POST'a GET'ом нельзя?

Comment: Отправить можно, но толку мало если они никак не обрабатываются сервером.

Comment: т.е. GET это бессмыслено делать? Ясно...Подождём ещё Версий :).

Comment: @Expert Спасибо :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Замечание**
>
> Главное отличие методов POST и GET
> заключается в способе передачи
> информации. В методе GET параметры
> передаются через адресную строку, т.е.
> по сути в HTTP-**заголовке** запроса, в то
> время как в методе POST параметры
> передаются через **тело** HTTP-запроса **и
> никак не отражаются на виде адресной
> строки**.

Comment: AlexWindHope http://www.webcorp.ru/page/php_post_get.html текста много, но сама суть в 4 пункете внизу страницы.

Answer (score 3):

Я так понимаю, вы на своей странице хотите разместить сию ссылку?
Тогда вопрос:

```
<form id="form" action="урл.страницы.почты>
<input type="hidden" name="имя.post.параметра" value="идентификатор">
</form>
Для перехода на страницу почты жми <a href="javascript:form.submit()">сюды</a>
```

Добавлено:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var request = new XMLHttpRequert();
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.open("POST","server.php", true);
request.send("somedata=somevalue");
</script>
```

Тело запроса формируется здесь:

```
request.send("somedata=somevalue");
```

Comment: Мане нужна сылка... а не скрипт....вернее можно и скриптом но сылкой будет лучше...и поэтому думаю - реально ли это вообще?

Answer (score 1):

GET это отправка параметров серверу через адресною строку, а вот POST это отправка так сказать в скрытом виде, все бы сработало если их серваки умели бы принимать данные и по Get и по POST...

Comment: @AlexWindHope я знаю прекрасно, что их серваки умеют обрабатывать и GET и POST я просто имел, что у них параметр можно принять только через глобальную переменную `$_POST`, а вот если бы у они написали и $_GET то тогда бы все было бадричком.

Comment: @Jagry а разве ajax может отправлять запрос к другому домену??? LOL

Answer (score 0):

Ну используйте куки, если я вас правильно понял то примерно так:

```
<input name="id" value="<?=$_COOKIE['previous_id'];"/>
```

и отправляйте себе постом сколько вам угодно :)

Т.е. при первой отправке инициализируем куку, а дальше просто пихаем в Input

Вообщем реально решение 1о - написать свою страницу с формочкой и там уже работать со своими куками...
в формочку просто указать `action="url_to_site"`

Сути так и не понял... Вы хотите чтобы сайт обрабатывал параметры которые не предусмотрены в обработке не имея доступа к серверу?О*о

 Тогда это невозможно...*




***Миха Николаев** 
POST это отправка с заголовком

Content_type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Писать что эти данные скрытие не совсем правильно, если их не видно в URL адресе это еще не значит что они скрыты


Их серваки умеют принимать и гет и пост LOL.. Просто GET не обрабатывается.




**Palmervan** - как это в ТЕЛЕ?О*о поясните мне грешнику, я приведу банальный прмиер на JS, а вы мне покажете где я там формирую ТЕЛО xD

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var request = new XMLHttpRequert();
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.open("POST","server.php", true);
request.send("somedata=somevalue");
</script>

и сервер

<?
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

И де я тут формирую ТЕЛО? и вообще о каком ТЕЛЕ вы писали? xD



**Ужас, товарисчи кагБы GET данные формируются примерно точно так-же как и POST данные, не? Если мыслить так как вы, то когда мы отдаем GET мы тоже формируем тело(для меня вообще непонято о каком ТЕЛЕ речь xD) Что POST что GET - строка, разница в загловке Content-Type, ВСЕ!**

Comment: эм...Эт как бы не Мой сайт (Как не жаль :D). Куки же Сайт читает. Как же я тогда код изменю чтоб Он мне каждый раз вставлял туда куда мне надо Мои куки? :)